# convert string value to dictionary from pickled

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, dictionary

```
val = "{t:30, f:50}"
```

is a string value and i need to convert it into dictionary other than the conventional method of using val.split(',') and then remove brackets and take out key and bind value to it and convert it in dictionary. Can anyone suggest any better approach towards it. PLz do care that even there is no quotes in strings in keys(t and s). Got some values from db.Already tried json loads or dumps.

Comment: what's wrong with the "conventional" method of using split()?

Comment: its not too smart as i already told that we need to follow several steps after splitting too. like stripping brackets from keys and some more as stated

Comment: Since the format isn't standard (e.g. it's not a valid json), I see no way around writing the parser yourself, e.g. using split()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import re
x="{t:30, f:50}"
y=re.findall(r"([^ {,]*):([^ {,]*)[,}]",x)
print dict(y)
```

Try this.Simple and done in one or two steps.

Comment: got it i haven't tried regular expressions thanks @vks

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
val = "{t:30, f:50}"
t = re.search("[^{].*[^}]",val).group()
print (t)
z = t.split(",")
print (z)
mydict = {}
mydict[z[0][0]]=z[0][2]+z[0][3]
print (mydict)

>>> 
t:30, f:50
['t:30', ' f:50']
{'t': '30'}
>>>
```

Use `search()` method of`re` module